# How to make a REST API call from SOAP

Tags: rest, web-services, soap

I would like to know the best practices of calling a REST API from SOAP.

Requirement:

We have a SOAP-based web service that is already consuming by many applications. we would like to rewrite the SOAP API with Rest(basically a Spring boot application), but we want to call the rest from SOAP to support the existing applications.

The one way I know is we can call the Rest Api from the SOAP server implementation class

EX: Consider EmployeeService;java is a SOAP implementation class

EmployeeService.java

```
   getEmployee(){
   Calling new Rest Api 
  }

Existing app1 ---->SOAP --> REST API  
Existing app2 ---->SOAP --> REST API  
new app1 --> REST API.
```

Please let me know is there any best way\alternate way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boomerang soap client. 
Detail [here](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000277254-How-to-run-a-SOAP-call-through-REST-URL-connector)